# Syntax error while running bash script

Tags: command-line, bash

I'm trying to run a script in terminal as follows:

```
bash <( curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/EpicCrypto/Epic-MN-Install/master/install.sh )
```

When I run it I get the following error:

```
-sh: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Anyone know why??

Thanks xx

Answer (score 2):

`<(...)` aka process substitution is bash syntax, and you're executing this in `sh` (note that your error starts with `-sh`). It seems your login shell is `sh`, not `bash`, for some reason. The simplest way here would be to switch to bash, and then run the command:

```
$ bash
$ bash <( curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/EpicCrypto/Epic-MN-Install/master/install.sh )
```

Ask your system admin how to change your login shell to bash.

Comment: Thanks - still getting the error though

Comment: Did you actually run bash? Are you using Ubuntu?